# Need to skip in loop and continue when request.get throws an error

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, python-requests

So I'm using the below code to scrape a CSV of Business Names & Website domains (about 10,000) for "mailto:" links and trying to save those to a CSV when mailto links are found. But occasionally I run into "temporary dns lookup failur" and "connection time out" errors.

I need help figuring out how to go about having it "Skip" when the request function throws these errors (any error) and just continue down the list.

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import numpy as np
results = []
agency_names = ['Agency Name']
agency_websites = ['Website']
agency_emails = ['Email Address']
with open('agencies_clean.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile) # change contents to floats
    count = 0;
    for row in reader: # each row is a list
       if count != 0:
        if row[1] != "":
            print("working on "+row[1]+"...")
            page = requests.get('http://'+row[1])
            soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
            mailtos = soup.select('a[href^=mailto]')
            if mailtos:
                agency_names.append(row[0])
                agency_websites.append(row[1])
                agency_emails.append(mailtos[0].text)
                print('Completed[x] Company:' + row[0] + 'Email: '+mailtos[0].text)
       count=count+1  
    np.savetxt('scrapes/agencies_w_emails.csv', [p for p in zip(agency_names, agency_websites)], delimiter=',', fmt='%s')
```

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for something similar to:

```
for row in reader:
   try:
      // your verification code here
   except DNSException:
      continue
```

I'm not sure about the exception name you should use, I think you can read it from the python interpreter's output and replace DNSException with it.
A part from that, the main idea is to use continue to pass to the next element of the iteration.

A generic exceptions handler like this:

```
try:
    // something
except:
    pass
```

is usually not a good coding practice.

Answer (score 0):

This might work. The print in except are optional.

```
try:
    mailtos:
                agency_names.append(row[0])
                agency_websites.append(row[1])
                agency_emails.append(mailtos[0].text)
                print('Completed[x] Company:' + row[0] + 'Email: '+mailtos[0].text)
except:
    print('email error')
    continue
```